# Closure inside for loop, what is the inner IIFE for?

Tags: javascript

I have been working through this article on closures: [Understand Javascript Closures with Ease](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/)

The final example deals with a closure inside a for loop.

I understand why an IIFE is used to capture the current value of 'i' as 'j'. What I don't understand about this example is why there is a 2nd, inner IIFE wrapped around the return statement. (My comment is in caps in the code below).

The code seems to work just the same without the inner IIFE. [See CodePen here.](http://codepen.io/jsheldrake/pen/KrJGAx)

Is this inner function required for some reason, or is this just an oversight by the author?

```
function celebrityIDCreator (theCelebrities) {
var i;
var uniqueID = 100;
for (i = 0; i < theCelebrities.length; i++) {
    theCelebrities[i]["id"] = function (j)  { // the j parametric variable is the i passed in on invocation of this IIFE
        return function () {   //<--WHY DOES THIS INNER FUNCTION NEED TO BE HERE?
            return uniqueID + j; // each iteration of the for loop passes the current value of i into this IIFE and it saves the correct value to the array
        } () // BY adding () at the end of this function, we are executing it immediately and returning just the value of uniqueID + j, instead of returning a function.
    } (i); // immediately invoke the function passing the i variable as a parameter
}

return theCelebrities;
}

var actionCelebs = [{name:"Stallone", id:0}, {name:"Cruise", id:0},{name:"Willis", id:0}];

var createIdForActionCelebs = celebrityIDCreator (actionCelebs);

var stalloneID = createIdForActionCelebs [0];
console.log(stalloneID.id); // 100

var cruiseID = createIdForActionCelebs [1];
console.log(cruiseID.id); // 101

var willisID = createIdForActionCelebs[2];
console.log(willisID.id); //102
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner function, as you observed, has no practical effect. It doesn't make sense to use it.

It appears to be a holdover from the previous example in the article where a function was returned instead of a number.